# R shiny: how to hide a UI element but keep a default value?

Tags: r, shiny

In some cases, I need to re-use some sub-modules in my shiny app, but I need to show or hide some elements in the same module according to the needs.

When the element is hidden, I still want to assign it a default value. Because if I don't keep a default value, the parameter from this element will not be found in the server, which will cause some errors.

I want to do everything **in the UI only**.

Here is my demo code.

It is possible to do it?

```
mod_plot_ui <- function(id, showUI = FALSE){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    column(width = inputWidth,
           box(
             width = 12,
             inputId = "input_card",
             title = strong("Input Parameters"),
             status = "primary",
             if (isTRUE(showUI)) {
               div(
                 numericInput(inputId = ns("myValue"),
                              label = NULL,
                              min = 0,
                              max = 10,
                              value = NA,
                              step = 0.001
                              )
               )
             } else {
                 div(here I need to hide the numericInput element, but keep the default value as NA)
             }
           )
))}
```

Comment: have a look at shinyjs. https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/

Comment: @dww, thanks a lot for your help. I am trying not to use additional packages.

Comment: Next time please provide us with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add a `style` attribute to your `div` to achive this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

mod_plot_ui <- function(id, showUI = FALSE){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    column(width = 6,
           shinydashboard::box(
             width = 12,
             inputId = "input_card",
             title = strong("Input Parameters"),
             status = "primary",
             div(
               numericInput(inputId = ns("myValue"),
                            label = NULL,
                            min = 0,
                            max = 10,
                            value = NA,
                            step = 0.001
               ),
               style = ifelse(isTRUE(showUI), yes = "display:block;", no = "display:none;")
             )
             
           )
    ))}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_plot_ui("test1", TRUE),
  mod_plot_ui("test2", FALSE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    lapply(names(session$input), function(x){print(input[[x]])})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```